# How can i get the sum of a database table to a variable?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have a database table named `Deposit` and one of the column name in it is `30-12-2013`. The column has two values such as 54,26.

i want to get the sum of that column column into a variable. I use the following code:

```
con.Open();
SqlCeCommand cmd11 = con.CreateCommand();
cmd11.CommandText = "select sum(30-12-2013) from Deposit";
int result = ((int)cmd11.ExecuteScalar());
displaylabel.Text = result.ToString();
con.Close();
```

But, I am getting the value of variable 'result' as -3990.

Whats wrong with my code.. Please help me.. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Your column name is `30-12-2013` ? I just ... WHY ?

Comment: You have a column name called `30-12-2013` ? Please say NO!

Comment: In less than 24 hours your database table will be outdated :)

Comment: Your deposit table should have separate columns for date/time and amount. Then just use `SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Deposit WHERE ...`

Comment: whats wrong with the column name..?

Comment: thanks.. i got the answer.. i added the square bracket.. But, please any1 tell me whats wrong with the column names..?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has already been answered so instead of answering your actual question I am going to propose an alternative solution.

Instead of having a table as follows:

```
SomeColumn | 30-12-2013 | 31-12-2013 | 01-01-2014
-----------+------------+------------+------------
    A      |    540     |    100     |    246
    B      |    130     |     90     |    377
```

Have a normalised table:

```
SomeColumn |    Date    | Amount 
-----------+------------+--------
   A       | 2013-12-30 |  540
   A       | 2013-12-31 |  100
   A       | 2014-01-01 |  246
   B       | 2013-12-30 |  130
   B       | 2013-12-31 |  90
   B       | 2014-01-01 |  377
```

This means you don't require a new column for every day. So your query would become:

```
SELECT  SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM    Deposit
WHERE   Date = '20131230';
```

And if you wanted to reproduce your original structure you can use:

```
SELECT  SomeColumn,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Date = '20131230' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [30-12-2013],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Date = '20131231' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [31-12-2013],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Date = '20140101' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS [01-01-2014]
FROM    Deposit
GROUP BY SomeColumn;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b08e2/1)** *(Using SQL Server as it doesn't support SQL Server CE)*

Comment: thank u,sir.. i got it.. will u please tell me is there any way to get the row-wise sum.., so that i can find the total amount deposited by A,B,C..?

Comment: yes..  but,is there any way to use loop if i display the table in a datagridview..?

Comment: This sounds like it is morphing into a new question as I don't immediately understand why you would want to loop... I'd suggest asking anew question about this with the data in the format you are retrieving it from the database, how you are binding to your gridview and what you ultimately want to achieve.

Comment: i have to display this table in a datagridview.. thats why i asked this question..

Comment: Yes, it may have been why you asked this question, but it is not what you asked in this question. It is still two separate questions. Regardless, there is a very good way to not have to repeat the columns, normalise your database, then you can either pivot within your application layer, pivot [like this ](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b08e2/3) or use dynamic SQL to pivot the data.

Answer (score 16):

(30-12-2013) * 2 (because you have two entries) = -1995 * 2 = -3990

You have to use:

```
SELECT sum([30-12-2013])
FROM   dbo.Deposit
```

Comment: Sorry- they ARE supported

Comment: @ErikEJ - OK thanks for the clarification. Irrelevant comments ( about apparently conflicting [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174147.aspx)) removed.

Comment: what this -1995 mean?

Answer (score 6):

Try to use brackets for columns with unusual names -

```
cmd11.CommandText = "SELECT SUM([30-12-2013]) FROM Deposit";
```

Comment: i cant use 'dbo.Deposit'.. Error is displayed as "Table name is not valid"